# MAKING A SCHEDULE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I've been working on a Schedule on excel for me and my employees but every now and then we are missing coverage. My idea to fix this was create a formula that I could apply to the schedule to find out which days we would be missing coverage.

There are 18 employees(6 for Mornings, 6 For evenings, 6 For nights) but only 9 work per day, 3 per shift, 3 shifts, and each shift has 3 task (one per employee). 
I was hoping to see if anyone knew how to make a formula (probably =IF(AND(OR))
Where 3 shifts would read "Full-Coverage"

ex.

0600P 0600I 0600C each covered each day regardless of the person

This would be very helpful!
--M

Comment: Link to example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLTyT.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem and you can find the solution thoroughly explained page 142 onwards in Practical Management Science :

http://ingenieria-industrial.net/downloads/practicalmanagementscience.pdf

However, you will probably have to cover the use of the Solver as the solution is based on linear programming.

Another reference is Management Science Modelling

Both of these are authored by Winston and Albright.